# Kivy Custom Widget Sizing within a Layout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use a custom widget within a layout in another application, but instead of scaling correctly within the layout, it's taking up the entire screen.  Here's the .kv files, broken down to the relevant parts (I took out all the callbacks, which function as expected):

```
<NodeWidget>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size:root.size
        ToggleButton:
            size_hint: 0.10345, 1
            group: 'Ends'
            background_normal: 'Left_Up.png'
            background_down: 'Left_Down.png'
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.801724, 1
            background_normal: 'Center_Button_Up.png'
            background_down: 'Center_Button_Down.png'
        ToggleButton:
            size_hint: 0.094827, 1
            group: 'Ends'
            background_normal: 'Right_Up.png'
            background_down: 'Right_Down.png'
```

Below is the .kv file for the separate app that's importing the class from above and using it:

```
<NodeEditorWidget>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.size
        cols: 3
        Label:
            text: 'Test 1'
        NodeWidget:
            ...
        Label:
            text: 'Test 3'
```

Here's what I see when I run the test app now:

[image: Current Output]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this by moving it back to straight python, no .kv files.  Here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton

#This widget contains two buttons
#The buttons each expose two events
#Names still aren't functioning
class NodeWidget(BoxLayout):

    #We expose events:
    #on_press when the central button is pressed
    #on_release when the central button is released
    #on_press_right when the right button is pressed
    #on_press_left when the left button is pressed
    press = BooleanProperty(False)
    release = BooleanProperty(False)
    press_right = BooleanProperty(False)
    press_left = BooleanProperty(False)
    release_right = BooleanProperty(False)
    release_left = BooleanProperty(False)

    #Properties exposed to set internal properties
    title = StringProperty('')
    left_background_normal = StringProperty('Left_Up.png')
    left_background_down = StringProperty('Left_Down.png')
    center_background_normal = StringProperty('Center_Button_Up.png')
    center_background_down = StringProperty('Center_Button_Down.png')
    right_background_normal = StringProperty('Right_Up.png')
    right_background_down = StringProperty('Right_Down.png')
    font_name = StringProperty('Roboto')
    markup = BooleanProperty(True)
    padding_x = NumericProperty(0)
    padding_y = NumericProperty(0)

    #Which node is active
    active_left = BooleanProperty(False)
    active_right = BooleanProperty(False)

    #Object Properties for internal elements
    left_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    center_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    right_button = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NodeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        center = Button()
        left = ToggleButton()
        right = ToggleButton()
        left.size_hint = (0.10345, 1)
        center.size_hint = (0.801724, 1)
        right.size_hint = (0.094827, 1)
        left.background_normal = 'Left_Up.png'
        left.background_down = 'Left_Down.png'
        center.background_normal = 'Center_Button_Up.png'
        center.background_down = 'Center_Button_Down.png'
        right.background_normal = 'Right_Up.png'
        right.background_down = 'Right_Down.png'
        left.group = 'ends'
        right.group = 'ends'
        left.bind(on_press=self.ActivateNode_Left)
        left.bind(on_release=self.ReleaseNode_Left)
        right.bind(on_press=self.ActivateNode_Right)
        right.bind(on_release=self.ReleaseNode_Right)
        center.bind(on_press=self.PressNode)
        center.bind(on_release=self.ReleaseNode)
        self.left_button = left
        self.center_button = center
        self.right_button = right
        self.bind(title=self.SetTitle)
        self.bind(left_background_normal=self.SetLeftBackgroundNormal)
        self.bind(left_background_down=self.SetLeftBackgroundDown)
        self.bind(center_background_normal=self.SetCenterBackgroundNormal)
        self.bind(center_background_down=self.SetCenterBackgroundDown)
        self.bind(right_background_normal=self.SetRightBackgroundNormal)
        self.bind(right_background_down=self.SetRightBackgroundDown)
        self.bind(font_name=self.SetFontName)
        self.bind(markup=self.SetMarkup)
        self.bind(padding_x=self.SetPaddingX)
        self.bind(padding_y=self.SetPaddingY)
        self.add_widget(left)
        self.add_widget(center)
        self.add_widget(right)

    def ActivateNode_Left(self, *args):
        if self.active_left == False:
            self.active_left = True
            self.active_right = False
        else:
            self.active_left = False
            self.active_right = True
        if self.press_left == True:
            self.press_left = False
        else:
            self.press_left = True

    def ActivateNode_Right(self, *args):
        if self.active_right == False:
            self.active_right = True
            self.active_left = False
        else:
            self.active_right = False
            self.active_left = True
        if self.press_right == True:
            self.press_right = False
        else:
            self.press_right = True

    def ReleaseNode_Left(self, *args):
        if self.release_left == True:
            self.release_left == False
        else:
            self.release_left == True

    def ReleaseNode_Right(self, *args):
        if self.release_right == True:
            self.release_right == False
        else:
            self.release_right == True

    def PressNode(self, *args):
        if self.press == True:
            self.press = False
        else:
            self.press = True

    def ReleaseNode(self, *args):
        if self.release == True:
            self.release = False
        else:
            self.release = True

    def SetTitle(self, *args):
        self.center_button.text = self.title

    def SetLeftBackgroundDown(self, *args):
        self.left_button.background_down = self.left_background_down

    def SetLeftBackgroundNormal(self, *args):
        self.left_button.background_normal = self.left_background_normal

    def SetCenterBackgroundDown(self, *args):
        self.center_button.background_down = self.center_background_down

    def SetCenterBackgroundNormal(self, *args):
        self.center_button.background_normal = self.center_background_normal

    def SetRightBackgroundDown(self, *args):
        self.right_button.background_down = self.right_background_down

    def SetRightBackgroundNormal(self, *args):
        self.right_button.background_normal = self.right_background_normal

    def SetFontName(self, *args):
        self.center_button.font_name = self.font_name

    def SetMarkup(self, *args):
        self.center_button.markup = self.markup

    def SetPaddingX(self, *args):
        self.center_button.padding_x = self.padding_x

    def SetPaddingY(self, *args):
        self.center_button.padding_y = self.padding_y
```